# image frame borders in pdf from latex template with pandoc, markdown

Tags: graphics, pdf, templates, pandoc, border

I'm using a tex template similar to 
https://github.com/davecap/markdown-latex-boilerplate/blob/master/template.tex

How can I get a frame around images which are passed from standard markdown code to the tex template?

Obviously this code handles the image sizes, but how can I add the graphics frames?

```
$if(graphics)$
\usepackage{graphicx,grffile}
\makeatletter
\def\maxwidth{\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\linewidth\linewidth\else\Gin@nat@width\fi}
\def\maxheight{\ifdim\Gin@nat@height>\textheight\textheight\else\Gin@nat@height\fi}
\makeatother
% Scale images if necessary, so that they will not overflow the page
% margins by default, and it is still possible to overwrite the defaults
% using explicit options in \includegraphics[width, height, ...]{}
\setkeys{Gin}{width=\maxwidth,height=\maxheight,keepaspectratio}
$endif$
```

...

```
\begin{document}
$body$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Without editing the template, you can use the [YAML metadata block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) to pass options that would redefine `\includegraphics` so that it would always add a frame, [similarly to what is done here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375041/34551).

Take, i.e., this picture as an example, and let's call it `Screenshot_20200131_230154.png`:

[image]

Then, the following markdown file `test.md`:

```
---
header-includes: |
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics
    \renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphicsbak[frame,#1]{#2}} 
---

![](Screenshot_20200131_230154.png){ width=150px height=150px }
```

would produce, when compiled with `pandoc test.md -o test.pdf`:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find how to make the yaml template work so I used @Clément's options as CLI parameters:

```
pandoc --pdf-engine xelatex \
    […]
    -V header-includes:'\usepackage[export]{adjustbox} \let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics \renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphicsbak[frame,#1]{#2}}'
```