# Pass frame option to \includegraphics by default?

Tags: adjustbox, bounding-box

I'm a copy-editor and in my job I format papers for scientific journals. One of my task is (in some cases) to crop images to remove extra space between the images and the bounding box.

Usually I use to `\fbox` to visually check the amount of space between the images and the bounding box, but to do that I need to wrap each `\includegraphics` command with `\fbox{...}`.

My question is, is there a way to box all the images by default? Maybe using `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` in the preamble and pass the `frame` option to `\includegraphics` command by default.

Comment: Using the `draft` you would see how large the image is, however not the real white space

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I need to see the box "and" the image at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could redefine `\includegraphics` to use the `frame`-option like this:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics
\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\includegraphicsbak[frame,#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Another possibility is to redefine it to always use `\fbox` around it with

```
\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{\includegraphicsbak[#1]{#2}}}
```

In the latter case you'll always get the small gaps because of the `\fboxsep`-length (which you could reduce to `0pt` but this way you might break things in the document you edit).

EDIT: You might need `\LetLtxMacro` for the command, take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88007/117050) for explanations of `\LetLtxMacro`.

Comment: Both solutions work fine for my purposes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different version to `skillmon`'s solution, by defining a `framed` document/package option that and redefinition of `includegraphics`, that uses this option.

`extgraphicx` loads `graphicx` and passes the other options to that package.

This way `\documentclass[frame]{article}` is sufficient.

```
\begin{filecontents}{extgraphicx.sty}
\ProvidesPackage{extgraphicx}

\newif\ifframeused
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
% Define some option
\define@boolkey{extgraphicx.sty}[Gin@]{frame}[true]{%
  \typeout{Used}
}

%Pass the other unknown thingies to graphicx
\DeclareOptionX*{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{graphicx}}

\ProcessOptionsX*

\RequirePackage{graphicx}




\RequirePackage{xparse}


\let\graphicx@@includegraphics\includegraphics

\RenewDocumentCommand{\includegraphics}{O{}m}{%
  \begingroup
  \ifGin@frame
  \fbox{%
    \graphicx@@includegraphics[#1]{#2}%
  }%
  \else
  \graphicx@@includegraphics[#1]{#2}%    
  \fi
  \endgroup
}

\end{filecontents}



\documentclass[frame=false]{article}



\usepackage{extgraphicx}



\begin{document}
\includegraphics{ente}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Very nice solution, but maybe a bit overkill? :)

Comment: @Skillmon: A toy solution ;-)

Comment: Does `\includegraphics` need `\LetLtxMacro`? It didn't appear to me that way when I checked.

Comment: @Skillmon: I did not check -- there's a starred variant, however. I think, I can omit it

Answer (score 3):

If you use `\adjincludegraphics` instead of the normal `\includegraphics` then you can use `\adjustboxset` to set default keys for all images (but also all other `\adjustbox`s).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\adjustboxset*{frame=5pt} % * to add frame behind local keys, not before

\begin{document}
\adjincludegraphics[height=4cm]{example-image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I expected that using `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` would allow `\adjustboxset` to work directly with `\includegraphics`. Is this not true?

Comment: @CiprianTomoiagă: No, the `export` option just makes the key namesspace the same so `\includegraphics` gets the same keys. As the key list given by `\adjustboxset` must be processed internally and `\includegraphics` (which is not changed by `adjustbox`) does not do this these keys only work with `\adjincludegaphics` or `\adjustimage`. I recommend the later for new documents.