# Frame (fbox) around all minipages/includegraphics/

Tags: macros, minipage

To fine-tune figures with many panels etc., or also beamer slides, it would sometimes come in handy to quickly see the outlines of minipages, graphics, etc. This can be achieved by manually wrapping the respective objects in `\fbox{}` or -- in beamer -- `\frame{}` commands. However, that's tedious.

I imagine the simplest solution would be to **redefine minipage, includegraphics, subfigure, etc. in the header such that they are placed in an `\fbox{}` and thus are framed throughout the document**. These redefinitions could then simply be uncommented whenever frames are desired. Of course, all options etc. should still be supported. How can this be achieved?

Following is an example with two figures, first the original, then with manual fboxes. The goal is that with redefined commands, the first figure looks like the second.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

% Remove padding from fbox
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}

\newlength{\h}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\h}{0.5\linewidth}

\begin{figure}\centering
%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.02\linewidth}
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{\h}\centering\textbf{first row}\end{minipage}}\\
\rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{\h}\centering\textbf{first row}\end{minipage}}
\end{subfigure}
%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}\\
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}
\caption*{\textbf{first column}}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
%
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}\centering
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}\\
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image}
\caption*{\textbf{second column}}
\end{subfigure}
%
\caption{\ldots}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}\centering
%
\fbox{
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.02\linewidth}
\rotatebox{90}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\h}\centering\textbf{first row}\end{minipage}}}\\
\rotatebox{90}{\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\h}\centering\textbf{second row}\end{minipage}}}
\end{subfigure}
}
%
\fbox{
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\h]{example-image}}\\
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\h]{example-image}}
\caption*{\textbf{first column}}
\end{subfigure}
}
\hfill
%
\fbox{
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.45\linewidth}\centering
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\h]{example-image}}\\
\fbox{\includegraphics[height=\h]{example-image}}
\caption*{\textbf{second column}}
\end{subfigure}
}
%
\caption{\ldots}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

The solution for `\includegraphics` is as follows (thanks @Skillmon for pointing me [to it](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375041/72659)):

```
\let\includegraphicsbak\includegraphics
\renewcommand*{\includegraphics}[2][]{\fbox{\includegraphicsbak[#1]{#2}}}
```

How can the same be achieved for command blocks (minipage, subfigure)?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375041/117050), there it is done for `\includegraphics`.

Comment: You should use `example-image`, `example-image-a` or `example-image-b` for the images in your MWEs. Those are installed with the `mwe`-package (included in both TeXLive and MikTeX) and therefore installed on close to every PC running LaTeX. (I've edited your question changing that)

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to use these initially, but they didn't work on my computer (aparentlly `mwe` is not installed).

Comment: The `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` shouldn't be necessary if you use the `\fbox{\includegraphicsbak...}`-approach.

Comment: If you really want to use the boxing approach for editing, you should perhaps consider setting the `\fboxsep=-\fboxrule` (just inside the environments and commands you want to alter), as this way it shouldn't add any extra space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution that should work for `minipage`. The `\begin{minipage}...\end{minipage}` is (roughly) equivalent to

```
\begingroup
\minipage
...
\endminipage
\endgroup
```

so you need to save both `\minipage`and `\endminipage` with `\let` in the same way as for `\includegraphics`. To make an environment that sets the `minipage` in a frame you need to put it in a box. For this the `lrbox` environment puts the contents in a box and removes one level of grouping. Below I first use the default `minipage` and then redefines it (normally the definitions should be before `\begin{document}`). It should also work with the optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}[]{0.8\linewidth}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\let\minipagebak\minipage
\let\endminipagebak\endminipage
\newsavebox\TestBox
\renewenvironment{minipage}[2][]
{\begin{lrbox}{\TestBox}\begin{minipagebak}[#1]{#2}}
{\end{minipagebak}\end{lrbox}\fbox{\usebox{\TestBox}}}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\linewidth}
  \lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You don't necessarily need `lrbox`, it works with `\newbox\TestBox` and `\setbox\TestBox\hbox\bgroup...\egroup`, too

Comment: @Skillmon, Yes, that should work also. It is close to the definition of `lrbox`.